# How to create 100 subdirectories using a Bash script?

Tags: command-line

I am trying to create 100 different subdirectories in certain directories using a Bash script.

I start with a basic `for` loop (that is, `for f in $FILES;do mkdir f done`), but it doesn't work.

To be clear on what I want to do: I try to obtain 100 different subdirectories in current directories (here I use `home='pwd'`). For example, in directory `/home/paul/main_directory/`.

And here I would like to create 100 directories with index from 1 to 100, like this:

```
subdirectory_1
subdirectory_2
subdirectory_3
subdirectory_4
.
.
.
subdirectory_100
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To answer your question using your suggested `for` loop - the brace expression mentioned by steeldriver works as well:

```
for i in {1..100}; do mkdir subdirectory_$i; done
```

To answer your updated question:

Both - the answer by steeldriver and the one by me are both meant to be one-liners.

If you would want to use this in a Bash script, you'd probably write it like:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..100}
do
    mkdir subdirectory_$i
done
```

Comment: an alternative for cases where you don't have a full BASH but just a /bin/sh, you can use `seq` instead:

`for i in $(seq 1 100); do mkdir dir_$i; done`

Comment: Creates a directory '{1..3}', when tried doing the same 3 times. Any clues what might have went wrong ?

Answer (score 43):

The easiest way is probably to use *brace expansion*

```
mkdir subdirectory_{1..100}
```

Comment: To add a little something to the truly impressive answer given by steeldriver: You can create directories that sort "properly" by padding with zero. `mkdir subdirectory_{001..100}`

Comment: Creates a sub-directory named 'subdirectory_{001..100}'. Any clues as to what might have gone wrong.

Comment: No idea. It works just fine for me here. Are you using bash?